# Changing the bounds of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a question that asks me to find the derivative of this integral, with out evaluation the intergral.

$$\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x}\frac {1}{1-t^2}dt$$

I think I need to use U-substitution and the chain rule, but I cant figure out how to apply it in this case.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: You need to introduce a "cut number" in order to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  You want to write your integral as $$ \ \frac{d}{dx} \ \int_u^a \ f ( x ) \ \ dx \ \ + \ \frac{d}{dx} \ \int_a^v \ f(x) \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ \frac{d}{dx} \ \left[ \ -\int_a^u \ f ( x ) \ \ dx \ \right] \ \ + \ \frac{d}{dx} \ \int_a^v \ f(x) \ \ dx , $$ together with  $$ \ \frac{d}{dx} \ \int_a^w \ f ( x ) \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ f ( w ( x )  ) \ \cdot \ \frac{dw}{dx} \ . $$  Differentiation "under the integral sign" can be a useful method to know, particularly for an integral with no elementary anti-derivative.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner. It is amazing (at least, to me) to see how are used the "different" versions of the FTC. I only learnt one, long long time ago. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  The strange part to me is that I'd seen the version of FTC using a function of $ \ x \ $ as the upper limit of integration referred to somewhere as "Leibniz' Rule".  So I was going around calling it that until I found out most people call something else (the generalization of the Product Rule) by that name.  On searching just now, I see that what you and I wrote is called Leibniz' _Integral_ Rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only elementary calculus is required. Note that I prefer using differentials(which is basically an implicit u substitution).
Recall the fundamental theorem of calculus, for a constant $a$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t) dt = f(x)
\end{equation}
so
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} \frac{1}{1 - t^2} dt &= \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{\cos x} \frac{dt}{1 - t^2} - \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{\sin x} \frac{dt}{1 - t^2}\\
&= \frac{d(\cos x)}{dx} \frac{d}{d(\cos x)}\int_0^{\cos x} \frac{dt}{1 - t^2} - \frac{d(\sin x)}{dx} \frac{d}{d(\sin x)} \int_0^{\sin x} \frac{dt}{1 - t^2}\\
&= \Big(-\sin x\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{1 - \cos^2 x}\Big)  - (\cos x)\Big( \frac{1}{1 - \sin^2 x}\Big)\\
&= \frac{-\sin x}{\sin^2 x} - \frac{\cos x}{\cos^2 x}\\
&= -\Big(\frac{1}{\sin x} + \frac{1}{\cos x}\Big)\\
&= - \csc x - \sec x
\end{align}

Comment: That's right, $-(\text{sc }x+\csc x)$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yeah sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: Otherwise, good one. I did it different: $$\int{1\over1-t^2}dt=\text{artanh }t+c$$ but then I had to get its derivative again, so your solution is definitely better

Comment: @Heimdall The OP asked how to do it without evaluation of the integral.

Comment: @IanMiller Oh, yes, I missed that. Got ahead of myself... Moral: Finish reading the question before you start answering it. :-)

Answer (score 5):

As carmichael561 commented, the  fundamental theorem of calculus tells that $$\frac d {dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, dt=f(b(x)) b'(x)-f(a(x)) a'(x)$$ For your case $$a(x)=\sin(x)\implies a'(x)=\cos(x)$$ $$b(x)=\cos(x)\implies b'(x)=-\sin(x)$$ $$f(b(x))=\frac 1{1-\cos^2(x)}=\frac{1} {\sin^2(x)}$$ $$f(a(x))=\frac 1{1-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{1} {\cos^2(x)}$$

Just finish.

Comment: I like this one much better because d(cos x) makes me uneasy. That reads like trouble especially for someone unexperienced.

Comment: @chx: $d(cos(x))$ is actually fine and can be made rigorous, but there are pitfalls. The easiest way to formalize it is to have a separate parameter, say $t$, with which all variables vary, and then define $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be the limit of $\frac{Δy}{Δx}$ as $Δt \to 0$ **if it exists and if $Δx \to 0$ as $Δt \to 0$**, where $Δv$ denotes the change in variable $v$, and $\to$ means "tend to but not equal to". If you don't impose the second part of the condition you'll get nonsense, and if you allow the denominator to keep hitting zero you'll also get nonsense.

Comment: @chx: In this case $cos(x)$ is nicely behaved (isolated zeroes) so it works. Though I still would fault both answers for not excluding the $x$ that would give rise to division by zero!